# tapestry M2_REPO ( A huge list of jar file is added )

Tags: eclipse, maven, repository, tapestry

In Eclipse, I added the path 
Windows-> Preference -> Java ->Build Path -> Classpath Variables -> click New and added the following:

```
Name = M2_REPO
Path = C:\Document and Settings\Uday\.m2\repository
```

BUT THIS INCLUDES A HUGE LIST OF JAR FILES IN MY ECLIPSE PROJECT BAR. 
So, Can anybody please tell me, how to include the folder containing files. So that the folder is visible in project bar and not every file.

Comment: ... and why would you do that? Please just install the Eclipse Maven Plugin, configure it (if you need to) and forget about modifying your classpath variables. Then create a new Maven Project and I promise you will see only the JARs for the dependencies you defined in your POM file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not try to mess with the classpath, it's a waste of time.

Instead

1. get Eclipse
2. get Eclipse [Maven Plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)
3. and follow this [Eclipse-Maven-Tapestry tutorial](http://bbwebcraft.blogspot.com/2008/12/task-1-create-skeleton-tapestry-5.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was thinking not to use maven repo from eclipse and directly import it. but the solution provided worked like charm. Thanks man.